# Oracle substring function of variable length

Tags: oracle, substring

I have a column containing filenames where I am trying to isolate the vaccine portion of the text. I need to cut off the beginning of the string up to the underscore. Then I need to cut of the file extension including the period, which could be four or five characters. I have the first part working, but it is not doing the second part. What am I missing? Should I use regexp instead of my 2nd instr? If so, how?

Here are the original values.

```
4212406_Meningitis.jpg
4824729_Hep-B.jpg
3612290_Hep-B.jpg
2811504_Covid-19.jpeg
621980_Covid-19.pdf
5258652_MMR.jpeg
5755663_Meningitis.png
2555841_Covid-19.PNG
2677160_MMR.jpg
2294961_MMR.jpg
```

```
SELECT original_field, 
       SUBSTR(original_field, INSTR(original_field, '_') + 1, INSTR(original_field, '.') -1) AS current_field
FROM my_table
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your sample data as text, so we can copy/paste it and test some code against it.

Comment: The third argument to `substr()` is the length of the sub-string, not the end position. You would need to work out the number of characters between the underscore and period. Or do it with nested `substr()` calls. Or use a regular expression, which might be slower but easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTR` has the signature `SUBSTR(value, start_position, substring_length)` (rather than having the third argument as end position). You can use:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       SUBSTR(original_field, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos) AS current_field
FROM   (
  SELECT original_field,
         INSTR(original_field, '_') + 1 AS start_pos,
         INSTR(original_field, '.', -1) AS end_pos
  FROM   my_table
);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       SUBSTR(
         original_field,
         INSTR(original_field, '_') + 1,
         INSTR(original_field, '.', -1) - INSTR(original_field, '_') - 1
       ) AS current_field
FROM   my_table;
```

or, shorter to type but slower to execute:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(original_field, '_(.*)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS current_field
FROM   my_table;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( original_field ) AS
SELECT '4212406_Meningitis.jpg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345_Small_Pox.version_2.jpg' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| ORIGINAL_FIELD | CURRENT_FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 4212406_Meningitis.jpg | Meningitis |
| 12345_Small_Pox.version_2.jpg | Small_Pox.version_2 |

---

Or, if you want the first `.` character instead of the last then:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       SUBSTR(original_field, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos) AS current_field
FROM   (
  SELECT original_field,
         INSTR(original_field, '_') + 1 AS start_pos,
         INSTR(original_field, '.') AS end_pos
  FROM   my_table
);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       SUBSTR(
         original_field,
         INSTR(original_field, '_') + 1,
         INSTR(original_field, '.') - INSTR(original_field, '_') - 1
       ) AS current_field
FROM   my_table;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT original_field, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(original_field, '_(.*?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS current_field
FROM   my_table;
```

Which all 3 output:

| ORIGINAL_FIELD | CURRENT_FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 4212406_Meningitis.jpg | Meningitis |
| 12345_Small_Pox.version_2.jpg | Small_Pox |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nNipQ5eZ)

Comment: Thanks MTO. I didn't know you could do that with the multiple INSTR functions. I may end up using the REGEXP, because that was what I have been trying anyway.